# how can I remove DataTable attributes using another function?

Tags: javascript, ajax, datatables

I have a function in my js file that generates a DataTable like this code below:

```
function GenerateTable(from,to){

    table = $('#report').DataTable( {
        "ajax": "webservices/getData.php?from="+from+"&to="+to, 

        "columns": [
        { "data": "period" },
        { "data": "id" },
        { "data": "date" },
        { "data": "debit" },
        { "data": "credit" },
        { "data": "remark" },
        { "data": "costcenter_id" },
        { "data": "costcenter_name" },
        ],
        "bPaginate": false,
        "paging": false,
        "destroy": true,
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "order": [[1, 'asc']],
    } );
}
```

Q:
How can I remove one or two attributes in DataTable using another function?

for example I want to remove:

> ```
>  "bPaginate": false, "paging": false,
> ```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say that you want to *remove one or two attributes in DataTable* you mean that you would like leave those attributes unset? Assuming your reply is 'yes' the solution could be to use the Javascript *delete* operator on the *table* object defined above:

```
function DeleteAttributes(mytable) {
  if(typeof(mytable.bPaginate)!=='undefined') delete mytable.bPaginate;  // or delete mytable["bPaginate"];
  if(typeof(mytable.paging)!=='undefined') delete mytable.paging;  // or delete mytable["paging"];
  }
```

You can invoke this function by calling *DeleteAttribute(table)* in your script.

Before deletion: table.bPaginate = false, table.paging = false after deletion, table.bPaginate = undefined, table.paging = undefined